# Redundant conformance of TableView to protocol UITableViewDataSource with Xib Files

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, xib

I have a parent view UIViewController (on storyboard),  a TableViewController with .xib and TableViewCell with .xib. I am trying to connect DataSource to the TableView however it's giving me an error:

> Redundant conformance of 'TableView1' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'
>
> 'TableView1' inherits conformance to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' from superclass here.

Without adding dataSource near class and try it as `class TableView1: UITableViewController {..` , it doesn't give me any error and in the simulator, I can see the table view illusion when I scroll down.

However, when I try to add dataSource, it gave me these errors.

The path I followed on setting it up...:

1. Ctrl + drag from xib to TableView1 and connected it as `Globals`
2. In xib file, I connected DataSource & Delegate

[image]

3. Finally, my TableView1:

`class TableView1: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource {` error here..

```
@IBOutlet var GlobalsTableView: UITableView!

var results: [AnyObject]? = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        print("A")
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return self.results?.count ?? 0
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! DogTableViewCell

    return cell
 }
}
```

Please note that in TableView1.xib, I can't select `TableView1` as Custom Class -> Class (but i don't think it's necessary).

Comment: What is the problem if you don't specify `UITableViewDataSource`? in your class  `class TableView1: UITableViewController { //... }`

Comment: I just removed it as you said. Apparently, I don't need it, I thought I needed it for passing data

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When a class inherits from `UITableViewController`, it by default conforms to `UITableViewDataSource` & `UITableViewDelegate` and you need not explicitly specify it.

You need to conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` only when you embed a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 conformations in your class. You need to extend only once.

First Scenario:

You conform in the class description AND in the extension.

```
class MyViewController: MyDelegate{
    //class functions here
}

extension MyViewController: MyDelegate{
func1()
}
```

Remove "My Delegate" in the class description.

```
class MyViewController{
    //class functions here
}

extension MyViewController: MyDelegate{
func1()
}
```

Second Scenario:

You conform in two extensions.

```
extension MyViewController: MyDelegate{
func1()
}

extension MyViewController: MyDelegate{
func2()
}
```

Merge them into one extension like:

```
extension MyViewController: MyDelegate{
func1()
func2()
}
```