# My custom cells are not showing up in my tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have been trying to get my custom cells to show up on this tableview, but I am not sure as to why they are not showing up

I have already checked other stack overflow questions and tried their fixes, to no avail. Please ignore the aws stuff as you can see I have the text hard coded so I can just get them to appear for now.

This is the code within the class holding the tableview

```
 import Foundation
 import AWSDynamoDB
 import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider
 import UIKit
// this will be the main feed class showing the user data 
class UserDetailTableViewController : UITableViewController {
// attributes for the custome cell

@IBOutlet weak var testing: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var Table: UITableView!
var response: AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse?
var user: AWSCognitoIdentityUser?
var pool: AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool?
var questiondata : Array<Phototext> = Array()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)
    if (self.user == nil) {
        self.user = self.pool?.currentUser()

    }
         // grabbing data from our aws table
    updateData()

    self.refresh()


}



override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
}


@IBAction func Questions(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ask", sender: self)
}


// MARK: - IBActions

@IBAction func signOut(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.user?.signOut()
    self.title = nil
    self.response = nil
    self.refresh()
}

 // reloads the prior view
 func refresh() {
    self.user?.getDetails().continueOnSuccessWith { (task) ->    
 AnyObject? in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.response = task.result
            self.title = self.user?.username
            // saving the user name from the main menu 
            username123 = self.user?.username! ?? "broken"
        })
        return nil
    }


  }
    // function that calls to our aws dynamodb to grab data from the    
     // user     
    //and re update questions
     // the array list

   func updateData(){
    let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    scanExpression.limit = 20
    // testing to grabt the table data upon startup
    let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
    dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(Phototext.self, expression:     
  scanExpression).continueWith(block: {    
   (task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error as NSError? {
            print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
        } else if let paginatedOutput = task.result {
            // passes down an array of object
            for Photo in paginatedOutput.items as! [Phototext] {
                // loading in the arraylist of objects
                // adding the objects to an arraylist
                self.questiondata.append(Photo)




            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //code for updating the UI

            }

        }

        return ()

    })

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // returning the number of rows
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:     
  IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
     "Questionpost", for: indexPath) as! QuestionCell

        cell.QuestionText.text = "call it"
        cell.Subject.text = "a day"

        return cell


    }


}

}
```

Here is the code for the QuestionCell class

```
import UIKit

class QuestionCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var Subject: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var QuestionText: UITextView!

 }
```

The cell class is called QuestionCell and the identifier I left on the cell in the storyboard is Questionpost

Here is a photo of my story board: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: There is, they are named subject and question, inside the content view of the cell.

Comment: I have updated the photos

Comment: The user details view controller contains the tableview in it has a cell called Questionpost, that cell has a content view containing those two text fields, sorry if I am missing some glaring error.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem because the text is black, I just tried it right now with a white text box and when I hard coded text in, it showed. I have updated the code to reflect my whole class. But I am not relying on the aws stuff right now because I am just trying to get the cells to show with this hardcoded text.

Comment: In the storyboard did you mark the User Details scene as a UserDetailTableViewController?

Comment: Try to override `heightForRowAt` method and give a static height value and see if your cells show. There might be other things wrong too but check this first.

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {` 
     `return 100`
 `}`

Also it doesn't look like you have set autolayout contraints for the objects added in your cell.

Comment: Did you try adding debug points in your tableview delegate callback methods, to see if they are even getting called? If not, there could be an issue with your logic on when to reload table.

Comment: Just tried it, you seem to be onto something because the breakpoint did not stop there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by declaring an extension with the proper types.

```
extension UserDetailTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // returning the number of rows
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Questionpost", for: indexPath) as! QuestionCell

    cell.QuestionText.text = "call it"
    cell.Subject.text = "a day"

    return cell


}}
```

good explanation of what's going on, you need to conform to the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate when you inbed a tableview.

[Redundant conformance of TableView to protocol UITableViewDataSource with Xib Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099847/redundant-conformance-of-tableview-to-protocol-uitableviewdatasource-with-xib-fi)